# A question about omission

Tags: meaning, grammar

Thanks a lot for reading my question about English grammar, and as you can see, I am an English novice, whose native language is Chinese.

I am learning an article written by Henry Moore entitled '[The Sculptor Speaks](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/research-publications/henry-moore/henry-moore-the-sculptor-speaks-r1176118)' and totally confused by a sentence of this article. Here is the original paragraph，which said:

> *And the sensitive observer of sculpture must also learn to feel shape simply as shape, not as description or reminiscence. He must, for example, perceive an egg as a simple single solid shape, quite apart from its significance as food, or from the literary idea that it will become a bird. ***And so with solids such as a shell, a nut, a plum, a pear, a tadpole, a mushroom, a mountain peak, a kidney, a carrot, a tree-trunk, a bird, a bud, a lark, a lady bird, a bulrush, a bone.*** From these he can go on to appreciate more complex forms or combinations of several forms.*

The sentence bewilders me is bold font in the quoted paragraph, and I am wondering why a sentence can be written like 'And so with...'. It is not that I do not know this is a sort of omission that is rarely mentioned by teachers or in grammar books, but I cannot get its accurate meaning.

Despite this, I have made a few attempt to get its meaning by filling the omission. There  the way: Absolute Construction.

And ***he must also feel shape simply as shape, not as description or reminiscence***  with solids such ***(being)*** as a shell, a nut, a plum, a pear, a tadpole, a mushroom, a mountain peak, a kidney, a carrot, a tree-trunk, a bird, a bud, a lark, a ladybird, a bulrush, a bone.

Does this right and precisely explain the author's point?

Answer (score 2):

Much depends on the meaning of **so**. I believe that is it used by Moore in this way:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so)
>
> so:
>
> used usually before the verbs "have", "be", or "do", and other auxiliary verbs to express the meaning "**in the same way**" or "**in a similar way**":

Moore is saying *and in the same way that an egg should be seen as a simple shape, the other listed things should be seen as simple shapes* (and not as their functions might suggest to us).

The parallelism implied by "*in the same way*" is between our **perception** of eggs and our **perception** of all the other things. From that viewpoint, your introduction of **being** is unnecessary.